# GraphQL.NET interface using ResolveType

Tags: c#, graphql, graphql-dotnet

I am new to GraphQL and I'm currently trying to build an api for a existing library.

There I have *Tags* which have an unique *alias*, a *value* which can be of different types and some *properties*.

To take care of the different *value* types, I have defined an interface containing *alias* and *properties* as well as 4 implementations with a differently typed *value* field.

The GraphQL schema is as follows:

```
schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}

type Query {
    allTags: [Tag!]
    tags(aliases: [ID!]!): [Tag]
    tag(alias: ID!): Tag
}

interface Tag {
    alias: ID! @isUnique
    properties: [TagProperty]
}

type StringTag implements Tag {
    alias: ID! @isUnique
    properties: [TagProperty]
    value: String
}

type IntegerTag implements Tag {
    alias: ID! @isUnique
    properties: [TagProperty]
    value: Int
}

type FloatTag implements Tag {
    alias: ID! @isUnique
    properties: [TagProperty]
    value: Float
}

type BooleanTag implements Tag {
    alias: ID! @isUnique
    properties: [TagProperty]
    value: Boolean
}

type TagProperty {
    name: String!
    value: String!
}
```

In the interface implementation in C#, I want to use [ResolveType](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#resolvetype) as suggested in the graphql-dotnet getting started docs.

The code for the interface implementation:

```
public TagInterface(
    BooleanTag booleanTag, 
    IntegerTag integerTag, 
    FloatTag floatTag, 
    StringTag stringTag)
{
    Name = "Tag";
    Description = "A resource which points to a value";

    Field<IdGraphType>(
        "alias",
        "the unique alias of the tag"
    );
    Field<ListGraphType<TagPropertyType>>(
        "properties",
        "the properties of a tag defined in the config XML"
    );

    ResolveType = obj =>
    {
        if (obj is HtTag)
        {
            switch ((obj as HtTag).DataType) {
                case EDataType.Bool:

                    return booleanTag;

                case EDataType.Byte:
                case EDataType.Sbyte:
                case EDataType.Short:
                case EDataType.Ushort:
                case EDataType.Int:
                case EDataType.Uint:
                case EDataType.Long:
                case EDataType.Ulong:
                    return integerTag;

                case EDataType.Double:
                case EDataType.Float:
                case EDataType.Decimal:
                    return floatTag;

                default:
                    return stringTag;
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Could not resolve graph type for {obj.GetType().Name}");
    };
}
```

}

When I run the following query

```
query {
    tags(aliases:["TagID_S1A02_IN","TagID_S1A03_IN"]) {
      __typename
      alias
      ... on StringTag {
        value
        }
      ... on IntegerTag {
        value
        }
      ... on BooleanTag {
        value
        }
      ... on FloatTag {
        value
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Für dieses Objekt wurde kein parameterloser Konstruktor definiert."
        }
    ]
}
```

This seems to be because of the 4 constructor parameters in the interface definition (which is according to the example in the docs). If I remove them and return `new StringTag()` etc. in the ResolveType implementation, I get the correct number of results, but without content:

```
{
    "data": {
        "tags": [
            {
                "__typename": "StringTag",
                "alias": null,
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "__typename": "StringTag",
                "alias": null,
                "value": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can anyone please point out to me what I'm doing wrong here?

### Update

I got it working by using the parameterless constructor and returning the resolved object like this:

```
ResolveType = obj =>
    {
        if (obj is HtTag)
        {
            switch ((obj as HtTag).DataType) {
                case EDataType.Bool:
                    return (from t in PossibleTypes where t is BooleanTag select t).First();

                case EDataType.Byte:
                case EDataType.Sbyte:
                case EDataType.Short:
                case EDataType.Ushort:
                case EDataType.Int:
                case EDataType.Uint:
                case EDataType.Long:
                case EDataType.Ulong:
                    return (from t in PossibleTypes where t is IntegerTag select t).First();

                case EDataType.Double:
                case EDataType.Float:
                case EDataType.Decimal:
                    return (from t in PossibleTypes where t is FloatTag select t).First();

                default:
                    return (from t in PossibleTypes where t is StringTag select t).First();
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Could not resolve graph type for {obj.GetType().Name}");
    };
```

Is this the way it is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to resolve your `TagInterface` type you will need to use some form of Dependency Injection.  Your `TagInterface` and all of the other `GraphType` schema types will need to be registered with your DI container.

If using the 2.0 pre-release, use the following (.NET Core example):

```
services.AddSingleton<ISchema>(
  s => new StarWarsSchema(new FuncDependencyResolver(type => (IGraphType)s.GetRequiredService(type))));
```

https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/blob/master/src/GraphQL.GraphiQLCore/Startup.cs#L29

Older versions you can just use a func directly (.NET Core example):

```
services.AddSingleton<ISchema>(
  s => new StarWarsSchema(type => (IGraphType)s.GetRequiredService(type)));
```

See these docs (not updated to the 2.0 alpha yet) for more info:

https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/dependency-injection

You may also need to register those Tag types using `RegisterType` on `Schema` if they are not publicly exposed somewhere else in your Schema.

> When the Schema is built, it looks at the “root” types (Query,
>   Mutation, Subscription) and gathers all of the GraphTypes they expose.
>   Often when you are working with an interface type the concrete types
>   are not exposed on the root types (or any of their children). Since
>   those concrete types are never exposed in the type graph the Schema
>   doesn’t know they exist. This is what the RegisterType<> method on the
>   Schema is for. By using RegisterType<>, it tells the Schema about the
>   specific type and it will properly add it to the PossibleTypes
>   collection on the interface type when the Schema is initialized.

https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/interfaces#registertype

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for you reply. I already register the interface implementations using `RegisterType<>()`. The types also get resolved correctly (see last code fragment in orig. post). When I set a breakpoint inside the alias resolve function of `StringTag`, the correct data is there too. But it does not return in the response!

Comment: I am confused, because you would only hit the error you posted if it is trying to create a type with `Activator.CreateInstance`, which is the default implementation.  You're saying that `TagInterface` was resolved, along with all of its constructor parameters?  What DI container are you using?

Comment: Played with this for a bit.  You'll want to make sure you're passing the DI resolver to the base class `Schema` class.  `TagSchema(IDependencyResolver resolver) : base(resolver)`.  You also want to make sure your *Tag types are registered as Singletons, since the instance resolved in the `ctor` may not be the same instance that gets registered with the `Schema` lookup.  That may be the two issues you ran into.

Comment: Well, im currently not using any DI containers and I'm on plain .Net 4.5 without ASP.NET... And I also do not directly use a dependency resolver.

Comment: The only way to use `ctor` injection is to use a DI container (which is not provided for you by graphql-dotnet), so that would be your problem.

Comment: well, I don't get how I would use that with the .Net Framework (not ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core). As written in the edited question, I found a solution in returning the type from within the `PossibleTypes` collection. But I would really like to understand it!